# Custom theme region for page

Tags: 7, theming

I would like to be able to custom theme a region for specific pages, is this possible? If so how?

For example I have a ragion called `rightbar` and I know the region can be themed using `region--rightbar.tpl.php` but is there a way of theming this using something like `page--node--1--region--rightbar.tpl.php`?

Or am I going to have to condition the `region--rightbar.tpl.php` script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code to achieve a solution to my answer.

```
/**
* Implements hook_preprocess_region().
*/
function care_preprocess_region(&$vars) {
    // Make sure we are on a single node page
    // This code will allow you to add the following templates for regions:
    // region--RNAME--node-NID.tpl.php
    // You can update the conditions to anything you want and rename the template
    // suggestions.
    if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && !arg(2)) {
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'region__' . $vars['region'] . '__node_' . arg(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_region().
 */
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_region(&$vars) {
  // Make sure we are on a single node page
  // This code will allow you to add the following templates for regions:
  // region--node-NID.tpl.php
  // You can update the conditions to anything you want and rename the template
  // suggestions.
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && !arg(2)) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'region__node_' . arg(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: will this allow me to specify a specific region?

Comment: Never mind I've worked it out, thanks for this though, it was a useful guide!